# Adding widgets to my launcher screen automatically

Tags: widget, system, launcher

I intent to put some widgets on my launcher screen without the need of the users to pick from the widget list.  I googled and found that this operation needs binding appWidgetId to AppWidgetInfo, which is only possible with the BIND_APPWIDGET permission.  i.e. this operation is only possible in system app (but my launcher is not).  Is my finding correct?

But I found that in GO Launcher, all its widgets can be put on the launcher screen automatically after download and installation.  GO Launcher and its widgets should not be system apps.  Any idea on how GO Launcher can implement the automatic widget adding to home screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999584/android-adding-appwidgets-to-an-activity/11464789#11464789)

The only issue remains that the added widget doesn't respond to clicks then.

Keep a track of answers here for a solution for that:
[Widgets don't respond when re-added through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470189/widgets-dont-respond-when-re-added-through-code)